# Installed Service Pack 3 for SQL Server 2005 but it does not show up when selecting @@version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We installed Service Pack 3 for SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition (64-bit). In the Add or Remove Programs menu we have the following entries under *Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (64-bit)*:

- Service Pack 3 for SQL Server Integration Services 64-bit) ENU (KB955706)
- Service Pack 3 for SQL Server Notification Services 2005 (64-bit) ENU (KB955706)
- Service Pack 3 for SQL Server Database Services 2005 (64-bit) ENU (KB955706)
- Service Pack 3 for SQL Server Tools and Workstation Components 2005 (64-bit) ENU (KB955706)

But when I run the following query on the server:

```
select @@version
```

I get this result:

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64)
Nov 24 2008 16:17:31
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Why does it not display that it is running Service Pack 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version 9.00.4035 uniquely identifies SP3, although it doesn't explicitly state SP3.  That SP2 that you see is referring to the operating system, not the SQL Server.  See [Microsoft's KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) on SQL versions.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking at the Windows NT Service Pack 2. Use Ctrl-T and then run your select and it will put the SQL and Windows on separate lines.